# PHP problem with die()

Tags: php, die

So, I have this code:

```
        } else {

            $photograph_moderation = new PhotographModeration($this->photograph_id);
            $photograph_moderation->purgePhotograph();

            //eventually take to an error page
            die('image is not big enough to upload');

        }
```

the purgePhotograph() function gets called properly when this condition is met, but the script never appears to die.  Is there a reason why die wouldn't get called here? purgePhotograph() has no script killing commands either.

Here's the purge_photograph function:

```
public function purgePhotograph() {

    $db = Connect::connect();
    $photograph_id = $db->real_escape_string($this->photograph_id);

    $query = "SELECT * from photographs WHERE id='{$this->photograph_id}'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $photograph = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if ($photograph['location'])
    unlink($photograph['location']);

    if ($photograph['thumbnail_location'])
    unlink($photograph['thumbnail_location']);

    if ($photograph['watermark_location'])
    unlink($photograph['watermark_location']);

    if ($photograph['xsmall_location'])
    unlink($photograph['xsmall_location']);

    if ($photograph['small_location'])
    unlink($photograph['small_location']);

    if ($photograph['medium_location'])
    unlink($photograph['medium_location']);

    if ($photograph['large_location'])
    unlink($photograph['large_location']);

    if ($photograph['xlarge_location'])
    unlink($photograph['xlarge_location']);

    if ($photograph['xxlarge_location'])
    unlink($photograph['xxlarge_location']);

    if ($photograph['xxxlarge_location'])
    unlink($photograph['xxxlarge_location']);

    $query = "DELETE from photographs WHERE id='{$this->photograph_id}'";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    $query = "DELETE from photograph_tags WHERE photograph_id='{$this->photograph_id}'";
    $result = $db->query($query);

}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it with just the three lines you provide, without the `eventually` stuff in between?

Comment: I've never seen die() fail.  What makes you so sure that purgePhotograph() ever exits?

Comment: @Anthony: I think that's a TODO comment, as in, eventually replace `die` with an error page :-)

Comment: Can you show the contents of the purgePhotograph method. The script could be throwing an error which is being suppressed by error reporting which occurs before the die.

Comment: And the code to purgePhotograph() as well as anything calling set_time_limit() is where? Not enough information ...

Comment: Do those DB calls silently fail by chance? That would explain why `die` is not reached. (hint: comment them out and see what happens)

Comment: FYI, you have an SQL Injection vulnerability there.  Inside the SQL, it should be `WHERE id = {$photograph_id}` NOT $this->photograph_id...

Comment: Thank you ircmaxell, I wouldn't have realized that if you didn't say something

Comment: @Josh: Yes, it's a TODO comment; just using die for testing purposes

Comment: ircmaxell: After changing to id = '$photograph_id', the die started picking up without the return 1;

Comment: There you go!  The problem was then in the query itself (likely an unescaped ' inside of the $this->photograph_id variable)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe now is the time to install a [php debugger module](http://de.php.net/manual/en/debugger-about.php) and step into the code in question.
[xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and e.g. [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) as the frontend work well enough.

Answer (score 2):

Check if purgePhotograph() returns. Maybe it has a deadloop or takes really long time.

Comment: Or just comment it out and see if die works then. If so you know the issue is with `purgePhotograph()`

Answer (score 1):

Wow, the problem was purgePhotograph() never had a return 1; at the end.  I didn't know this was required for following lines to execute.

Comment: "I didn't know this was required for following lines to execute."  It isn't.  Plenty of PHP built-in functions don't have a return statement (also referred to as returning `void` in the PHP manual) and execution continues normally.  This is likely indicative of some other problem.

Comment: It's not required.  There was some other problem that you must have inadvertently solved.  BTW:  Make sure to see my comment to the main thread...

Comment: Statements are all completing properly, I just put them in conditionals and tested each one

Comment: Have you checked the error log?  Could it have been the WSOD (White Screen Of Death)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it into an try/catch block.
Maybe something is throwing an exception before die can get executed.

Are you getting any error?